# ¿Porque en la consulta INSERT INTO no me muestra el dato de la variable?

Tags: sql

Hola estoy intentando hacer que en mi calendario php al hacer click me haga una consulta, por ahora me está yendo bien.

```
  <left class="coordinar_left">
    <select id="tipoEventos">
      <option selected disabled>-Editar...-</option>
      <option value="Vacaciones_de_Pascua">Vacaciones de Pascua</option>
      <option value="Vacaciones_de_Navidad">Vacaciones de Navidad</option>
      <option value="Dias_festivos">Dias festivos</option>
      <option value="inicio_de_curso">Inicio de curso</option>
    </select><textarea id="seleccionar_fecha" name="fecha_texto" hidden></textarea>
  </left>
```

y el php:

```
<?php
   $conexion= new mysqli("sql113.260mb.net","n260m_20445422","jyEsRoXZ","n260m_20445422_profesorado");
 if (!$conexion) {
   echo "error al conectar con la base de datos";
 }
 $fecha1 = $_POST["fecha_texto"];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO vacaciones_pascua (fecha) VALUES ('".$fecha1."')";
 if($conexion->query($sql)===TRUE){
   echo "1";
 }else{
   echo "0";
 }
 $conexion->close();
?>
```

El problema es que hago la prueba de imprimir la variable $sql para ver si me ejecuta bien y me sale esto: INSERT INTO vacaciones_pascua (fecha) VALUES ('');

es decir no me sale el valor que he puesto en el input

Al clicar una celda del calendario me imprime en un textarea el id con la fecha y eso tendría que guardar en la DB.

Pero no se porque es.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás mandando los datos desde el cliente (HTML/Javascript) al servidor?

Comment: tu error podria estar aca: <textarea id="seleccionar_fecha" name="fecha_texto" hidden></textarea>

Comment: si te fijas tienes id y name distintos debes usar el mismo para ambos ...

Comment: Pero cual podría ser? porque el name lo llamo bien.

Comment: No @Tegito123 eso no importa. Generalmente se usa `name` para obtener los datos del POST y si `name` y `id` son distintos no tiene por qué influir. La cuestión es que no se sabe cómo él está enviando los datos. Ese es el problema. No se sabe si por ejemplo en Javascript él cambia los nombres con los que envía la información, por eso mi pregunta, a la que el OP no ha respondido y que podría dilucidar dónde está el problema.

Comment: Otro elemento de depuración que puedes implementar es mostrar lo que hay en el POST mediante: `var_dump($_POST);` en la parte de PHP, ahí te mostrará las claves/valores que han sido pasadas por POST. Si el dato no te está llegando bien puede ser que hagas alguna manipulación extraña antes de enviarlo o que por algún error no se está enviando. Conviene que muestres el código a través del cual envías los datos al servidor.

Comment: ¿Como estas definiendo tu formulario? No estaras enviando los datos por GET

Comment: No, son por POST

Comment: como estas haciendo para poner los datos en <textarea id="seleccionar_fecha" name="fecha_texto" hidden></textarea>

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de ello para ver como recoges esos datos y despues cmo los mandas a tu archivo php.. para hacer el insert

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '.dates li', function(){
      var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
      $("#seleccionar_fecha").text($(this).attr('id'));
      setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"guardar_vacaciones.php",
          success:function(i){
            if (i==1) {
              alert("correcto");
            }else{
              alert("error");
            }
          }
        });
      },1000);
    });
  });
</script>

Comment: Tengo la impresion que tu script no manda nada por post. Te falta el data. Mira la parte de ejemplos de abajo http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Si la parte HTML que muestras en la pregunta está dentro del formulario cuyo id es: `form_fecha`, debería funcionar así: `<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("body").on('click', '.dates li', function() {
  var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
  $("#seleccionar_fecha").text($(this).attr('id'));
  setTimeout(function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: fecha,
    url: "guardar_vacaciones.php",
    success: function(i) {
     if (i == 1) {
      alert("correcto");
     } else {
      alert("error");
     }
    }
   });
  }, 1000);
 });
}); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

ya tengo la solución, los fallos eran varios.

En el HTML no tenía una etiqueta form, por cual me quedaría así:

```
<form method="POST" id="form_fecha"><textarea id="seleccionar_fecha" name="seleccionar_fecha" hidden></textarea></form>
```

En el script jQuery le hice unas modificaciones:
antiguo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("body").on('click', '.dates li', function(){
        var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
        $("#seleccionar_fecha").text($(this).attr('id'));
        setTimeout(function(){
          $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"guardar_vacaciones.php",
             success:function(i){
                 if (i==1) {
                     alert("correcto"); 
                 }else{ 
                     alert("error"); 
                 } 
             } 
        },1000); 
    });
});
```

actualizado:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on('mouseenter', '.dates li', function() {
    $("#seleccionar_fecha").text($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $("body").on('click', '.dates li', function(){
    var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"guardar_vacaciones.php",
        data:fecha,
        success:function(i){
          if (i==1) {
            alert("enviado");
          }else{
            alert("error");
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Por la cual le añadí, un `return false` para que no cargue la página al dar clic en una casilla del calendario y también le puse un la variable fecha que coge los campos name.

en el PHP:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("sql113.260mb.net","n260m_20445422","jyEsRoXZ","n260m_20445422_profesorado");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$fecha12= $_POST['seleccionar_fecha'];
$sql = " INSERT INTO vacaciones_pascua (fecha) VALUES ('$fecha12')";
echo mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
```

Primero no puse bien la tabla, no era 1esoacalendar sino vacaciones_pascua y al final tengo que imprimir el mysqli_query($conn,$sql), para que me imprima 1 o 0, y lo otro, es decir el POST estaba bien llamado.

**Finalmente quedaría así:**

HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" id="form_fecha"><textarea id="seleccionar_fecha" name="seleccionar_fecha" hidden></textarea></form>
```

jQuery:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on('mouseenter', '.dates li', function() {
    $("#seleccionar_fecha").text($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $("body").on('click', '.dates li', function(){
    var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"guardar_vacaciones.php",
        data:fecha,
        success:function(i){
          if (i==1) {
            alert("enviado");
          }else{
            alert("error");
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("sql113.260mb.net","n260m_20445422","jyEsRoXZ","n260m_20445422_profesorado");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$fecha12= $_POST['seleccionar_fecha'];
$sql = " INSERT INTO vacaciones_pascua (fecha) VALUES ('$fecha12')";
echo mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
```

**Gracias por vuestra colaboración**

Comment: Ahora te falta resolver un grave problema de seguridad: tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Debes aplicar consultas preparadas.